# Codeigniter 4 - unknown column 'namespace' in 'where clause'

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

While running "php spark make:migration Car" ,It runs without error but while running "php spark migrate" it throw error
"*Unkown column 'namespace' in 'where clause*'

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class Car extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'id' => ['type' => 'INT','usigned'=>true, 'constraint' => 5, 'unsigned' => true, 'auto_increment' => true],
            'parent_id' => ['type' => 'INT'],
            'name' => ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => 200],
            'email' => ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => 200],
            'password' => ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => 200],
            'created_at datetime default current_timestamp',
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('id', true);
        $this->forge->createTable('Car');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('Car');

    }
}
```

Comment: This migration runs fine for me. The problem must lay elsewhere.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you get the root cause or any solution?